# Find accessor methods in JavaScript code (node_modules)

Tags: javascript, code-analysis

I'm using a number of libraries in a project. One of them uses accessor methods `get` and/or `set` methods, that can't be translated or polyfilled in Internet Explorer 8.

How can I find which library uses the accessors; are there any tools that could help? I guess the only thing one could do is to parse every `.js` file and then analyze it's syntax tree to find the methods.

Comment: Is my answer in the right direction? Do you need any further explanations?

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov it worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `grep -r` with `/^\s*(?:get|set)\s+\S+/` but this regex should be converted to syntax of grep with which I'm not familiar. Also `node_modules` may be huge to search, so you may need to exclude some sub-trees.

Here is my try: `grep -r "^\s*\(get\|set\)\s\+\w" --include \*.js ./`
Output only files: `grep -r "^\s*\(get\|set\)\s\+\w" --include \*.js ./ | cut -d: -f1`